# Shell: Replacing each New Line "\n" character with "\\n"

Tags: json, perl, shell, scripting, escaping

I'm inserting a git diff of changed files into a JSON object to send using a curl request.

The problem is it doesn't like the new-line characters being inserted into the JSON but I'm not sure how to get around that. Translate tool didn't work, this perl solution I'm using is close but just replaces with spaces:

```
changedfiles=$(git diff --name-only $3..$4 | perl -p -e 's/\n/ /')
```

and changing it to this didn't help:

```
changedfiles=$(git diff --name-only $3..$4 | perl -p -e 's/\n/\\n/')
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It doesn't need to use perl, it just needs to work
(...being simple would be nice too)

Comment: Your second line seems to do exactly what you're asking for (one line, no trailing newline, newlines in the input changed to backslash escapes).  How are you using $changedfiles?  Is it possible you're giving it to a shell command that interprets \n escapes or munges the data in some other way?

Comment: @jcast It's just being put into a curl request in a json string

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want to do to get a quoted list of files separated by commas (i.e. for inserting into a JSON string):

```
git diff --name-only $3..$4 | perl -p -e 's/(.*)/"$1",/;s/\n//;s/""/","/'
```

This works if your files don't contain double quotes or special characters that need to be JSON escaped.

First, we put the files in quotes followed by a comma, then remove newlines, then change the `""` between files to `","`. Although, this is kind of a hack. Somewhat better might be:

```
git diff --name-only $3..$4 | perl -p -e '$/="";s/(.*)\n/"$1",/g;s/,$//'
```

Here we read in the whole input, newlines and all, do our substitution and remove the final comma.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do ad-hoc escaping for characters that your immediate testing finds problematic, how about using an actual JSON library that handles all of them in a solid way?

Here's an example in bash using inlined python:

```
python -c '
import json
import sys
print(json.dumps({"data": sys.argv[1]}))
' "$(git diff --name-only $3..$4)"
```

It prints the json object `{ "data": "your command output here" }` with standards compliant escaping.